# React Native - Browse device local storage

Tags: react-native

I would like to browse the local storage of the device in order to upload a file from it. Is there any kind of plugins allowing to do so? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by local storage of the device? The browser (Chrome) local storage?

Comment: I thought react native only capable to access async storage

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'm building an app for Android/iOS through RN and I would like to access the smartphone files and pick one to upload.

Comment: Are you looking for images? or just files stored on the device? I don't see one for the latter... if you know you could do this with Objective-C/Java you might have to write your own code natively for this and bridge it over.

Comment: I'm looking for any files on the device (PDF, MP3, JPG, ...). I'll keep searching but I think I'll have to go with native code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a plugin which allows me to browse the local filesystem. I used [react-native-file-picker](https://github.com/Lichwa/react-native-file-picker) which is based on *react-native-image-picker*.

Be careful if you use this plugin as, for now, it's only supporting react-native@0.32 so you need to make some adjustments in java files for newer version (tested & working on 0.35). You can take a look at react-native-image-picker which is working and make the changes needed.

FYI: https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/issues/350